# Keras classification model layout

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification

I want to use Keras (or any other NN lib if there's a better one) to categorize data.

The input looks like this:

```
train_x = np.array([ [[1, 3, 5, 7],
                      [4, 6, 8, 10]],

                     [[6, 3, 1, 7],
                      [4, 3, 9, 10]],

                     [[1, 9, 9, 7],
                      [5, 6, 3, 10]],

                    '''.
                       .
                       .'''
                  ])
```

The output looks like this:

```
train_y = np.array([1,0,1'''...'''])
```

This is the rest of my code so far:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(2,4))) 
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train model
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=30, validation_split=0.2, callbacks [early_stopping_monitor])
```

Originally, the first layer was a Dense layer too but that got me an error message because the output would be two dimensional so I replaced it by a Flatten layer.

The console output looks like this:

[image: Console output]

Obviously, it doesn't work and I suspect it's because of the layout of the model and its layers. Does anybody know how to properly build the model for this case?

Comment: I assume that's binary classification, change last layer activation to `sigmoid` and loss to `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: Indeed as @Frightera says

Comment: Thank you, loss and accuracy aren't just zero any more! However, the validation accuracy doesn't change at all from epoch to epoch. Is there something else that should be changed?